# Django RaspberryPi cannot connect to webserver

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi

I'm following this [website](https://linuxconfig.org/setting-up-django-python-and-mysql-development-environment-on-debian-linux-8-jessie) to connect raspberry pi with web server. All the steps are done correctly including the last one. Then I tried to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ but got this message from chrome:
"This site can’t be reached

127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

I didn't know what to do so just changed the last command into

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.0.29:8000
```

(192.168.0.29 is my RPi inet address)
and then chrome threw this line:
"A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator."
meanwhile on RPi, it threw an

```
ImportError: No module named 'django.middleware.security'
```

How do I solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: does ur pi has module `django` installed?

Comment: you should type address `http://192.168.0.29:8000` in ur chrome browser

Comment: Just guessing here but could it be a simple python2/python3 issue? What if you run `python3 manage.py runserver 192.168.0.29:8000`?

Comment: I've set up Django on a RPi several times but I always do it with python 2.7 and the latest version of Django (currently 1.9) and I've never come across this problem.  I tend to follow http://raspberrypituts.com/django-raspberry-pi-tutorial/.  Could you confirm first that you are trying to implement this on a clean RPi and it is an RPi 2.  If it's not a clean version could I suggest you start by reinstalling NOOBs and then attempt your installation again.

Comment: I tried typing address http://192.168.0.29:8000 but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually set up your django project by running `django startproject`?  That should set up the file structure for you correctly and you should be able to then run `manage.py runserver` and see your project running with the admin services run from your ip/admin.

Comment: yeah I did. I'll try the link you provided. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help - it might be worth copying down here and then marking as answered for others that have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

you should install django on your pi.

Using `pip`:

```
sudo pip install django
```

Using apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install python-django
```

Comment: Running the first command yielded:
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Cleaning up...

Comment: and an error after running second command:
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

Comment: @ClaireELi django is installed in ur pi , i think, you can check version `python -c "import django; print django.__version__"`

Comment: It's version 1.7.7

Comment: The tutorial I followed was using django 1.7.1
Does it matter a lot?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter, but 1.9 is out and it is easy to upgrade: sudo pip install --upgrade django. Aso view the messages that come in your terminal that you run the webserver, to see if you are having errors

Comment: I actually started from django 1.9 but got stuck even before the last step. I'll try another method now. Thank you!